# Assigning to map in golang

Tags: dictionary, go, assign

In the following go snippet, what am I doing wrong?

```
type Element interface{}

func buncode(in *os.File) (e Element) {
    <snip>
    e = make(map[string]interface{})
    for {
        var k string = buncode(in).(string)
        v := buncode(in)
        e[k] = v
    }
    <snip>
}
```

Compiling gives me this error:

```
gopirate.go:38: invalid operation: e[k] (index of type Element)
```

Double ewe T eff?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `buncode` function you declare `e Element`, where `type e Element interface{}`. The variable `e` is a scalar value, which you are trying to index.

> [Types](http://golang.org/doc/go_spec.html#Types)
>
> The static type (or just type) of a variable is the type defined by
>   its declaration. Variables of interface type also have a distinct
>   dynamic type, which is the actual type of the value stored in the
>   variable at run-time. The dynamic type may vary during execution but
>   is always assignable to the static type of the interface variable. For
>   non-interface types, the dynamic type is always the static type.

The static type of `e` is `Element`, a scalar. The dynamic type of `e` is `map[string]interface{}`.

Here's a revised, compilable version of your code.

```
type Element interface{}

func buncode(in *os.File) (e Element) {
    m := make(map[string]interface{})
    for {
        var k string = buncode(in).(string)
        v := buncode(in)
        m[k] = v
    }
    return m
}
```

Why are you making the recursive calls to `buncode`?

Comment: But I set it's type with the assignment from the make? I gathered from the spec on [type assertions](http://golang.org/doc/go_spec.html#Type_assertions) that the type would now be that of the "larger" type I'd assigned to it.

Comment: The recursive calls fetch the nested values for m. If you're interested, and have some idiomatic go-isms to propose, take a look here: http://code.google.com/p/erutor/source/browse/bencoding.py

Comment: @Matt (1) - The compiler doesn't track the dynamic type of an interface{} value, even if it can be statically known. You must use a separate variable with the correct type.

Comment: Are you sure this is going to compile ? You specify Element as a return value and you are returning map. I'm just curious if I'm missing something here.